# R - Scheduled Task not running

Tags: r, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a problem that is extremely bothering me. I scheduled a Task on Window's Task Scheduler (I am using Windows Server 2012 R2) but it is not running. That is:

- On the task's History, it says it did run but just lasted for less than 30 second: [see this capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9Ce8.png)
- It did not update the "Last Run Time" column [(see this capture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm5o4.png) (otherwise I would think that it's my code that it is not working).
- When I run the code myself it works perfectly

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks!!

Comment: do you run your R script using a batchscript? If so, can you share the batchscript command you use to run your Rscript?

Comment: No, I don't use a batchscript, I am scheduling the R file directly.

Comment: Using windows task scheduler, you have to run it using batchscript. Create a single line of code that will run your R script. something like: `C:\Program Files\R\R-xxx\R.exe C:\path\to\your\Rscript`. An R script cannot run alone without the R application to process it.